# Can't confirm the version of java 6 on CentOS 7

Tags: java, centos

I did install java 6 on my CentOS 7 with this command

```
yum install java-1.6.0-openjdk*
```

But when i checked the version of java using

```
java -version
```

It said: bash: /bin/java: No such file or directory

Here's the output about java folder

```
[root@ip-10-0-7-233 ~]# find / -name "java"
/etc/alternatives/java
/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/java
/etc/pki/java
/etc/java
/var/lib/alternatives/java
/usr/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.41.x86_64/jre/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.41.x86_64/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java
/usr/lib/java
/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java
/usr/share/java
/usr/share/javadoc/java-1.6.0-openjdk/api/java
/usr/share/javadoc/java-1.6.0-openjdk/api/org/omg/stub/java
/usr/share/javadoc/java-1.6.0-openjdk/jre/api/plugin/dom/com/sun/java
/usr/share/javadoc/java
```

I tried to access to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.41.x86_64/jre/bin` and `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.41.x86_64/bin` then executing `java -version` command but still got the same error.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Try `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.41.x86_64/jre/bin/java -version` This should work! It looks like you will need to edit your `$PATH` variable to have access to your `java`. or `/usr/bin/java -version`

Comment: Thanks Allan. I thought that i need to create a symbolic link but turned out i have to edit $PATH as you said.